# Use method security springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, jjwt

I using this sample (https://www.djamware.com/post/5c819d0180aca754f7a9d1ee/securing-restful-api-with-spring-boot-security-and-data-mongodb#ch5) to create a secured rest Api. but It`s possible to use the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to secure at method level?

how.. tks

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just annotate `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` on any `@Configuration` bean. A good one is to annotate on the configuration bean that configures security :

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Then you can use `@PreAuthorize`, `@PreFilter`, `@PostAuthorize` and `@PostFilter`  to configure a SpEL to secure a bean method :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public void create(Contact contact){

}
```

See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) for the available list of the built in SpEL that can be used to secure method.